# Show that a closed graph and compact codomain implies continuity.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $$f:X\rightarrow Y,$$ where *X* and *Y* are metric spaces and *Y* is compact. If  *f*  has a closed graph $$G_f=\{(x,f(x)):x\in X\},$$

then *f* is continuous.

My first instinct is to use the fact that if $${x_n}\rightarrow x \;\text{  and  }\; \{f(x_n)\} \rightarrow y$$ implies *x* is in *X* and *f(x)=y*, then showing the *f* is continuous at $(x,y)$, and so continuous on *X*. Having trouble getting direction on this.

Comment: @YuiToCheng Not sure that this is really a duplicate as the OP is adding the hypothesis that the spaces are metric spaces. This suggests to use a more elementary proof based on sequential compacity.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Then see [Analogue of closed graph theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/609112/analogue-of-closed-graph-theorem?rq=1) (That's the sequential argument you are hinting at?)

Comment: That is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @YuiToCheng Yes, this a real duplicate.